# how to convert array into dictionary in python?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, dictionary

basically I want to know that how to convert array into dictionary in python.

```
import numpy as np
a=np.array(\[23,34,23,45,23\])
print(a)
```

**output**
[23 34 23 45 23]

but i want

```
{0:"23",1:"34",2:"23",3:"45",4:"23"}
```

Comment: Okay, 1: I don't see any need for this action, 2: If you still want to do it, please show what you have tried.

Comment: Please check out: [How to ask and answer Homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/334823#334823)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the values in the array need to be converted to string when added to the target dictionary. Therefore:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([23,34,23,45,23])
d = dict(enumerate(map(str, a)))
print(d)
```

**Output:**

```
{0: '23', 1: '34', 2: '23', 3: '45', 4: '23'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Iteratively by enumerate() and using f-formatting for dict-members

```
mydict={}
for index, i in enumerate(a):
    mydict[index]=f"{i}"
    
print(mydict)
```

f-formatting:
https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#whatsnew36-pep498

Answer (score -1):

You can use comprehensions like

```
dic={i:a[i] for i in range(len(a))}
```

Comment: `dic = dict(enumerate(a))`…